# Short sci-fi story about animals fighting in nature while man is peaceful at home

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

My mom is looking for the title of this short story that she read when she was younger, I'd say between 1960 and 1975. It was gathered in a sci-fi collection of stories, that was published regularly and that she used to read. Although one could say that it doesn't sound like a science-fiction story, the decision by the writer to compare animal and human lifestyles, and to compare things happening at very different scales, and switch the "size" of his/her focus to very small things and create a fictional plot involving insects or animals makes it science-fiction-like I think.

In the story, a man wakes up in his house, opens the windows and looks out to the beautiful nature around him. He believes a fine day is about to start.
But a shift in perspective reveals terrible law-of-nature like fights that animals endure on a smaller, maybe invisible scale, portraying nature in a darker light than was shown at the beginning at the man's scale.

Comment: You need to add an estimated year when she read it.

Comment: Also, what is the science-fiction aspect of the story? Written like this, it sounds like a TV documentary.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it doesn't appear to be science-fiction or fantasy.

Comment: Based on the comments on your edits, it seems you have multiple accounts. You should get a mod to combine them.

Comment: Even with the edits it still sounds pretty off-topic.